# TYPO3: remove powermail validation

Tags: typo3

i've installed Powermail 1.6.8 in a TYPO3 version 4.5.

When I click on submit on an empty form, some error messages come that can#t be styled since they have inline styles. I would like to use a jQuery plugin to check the validation. How can I deactivate the normal powermail validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you have already found a solution, but by default you can change this with TYPO3 Constants:

```
plugin.powermail.js.validation = 0
```

If you select 'Template' and select "Constants Editor" in the dropdown that pops up in the third column (Backend), you are able to change a lot of settings yourself.

There is another setting that disables all javascript form validation and "special" input types from Powermail:

```
plugin.powermail.js.alwaysInclude = 0
```

More constants and setup for your Powermail 1.6.8 [can be found here](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/1.6.8/view/1/6/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add

```
page.includeJSFooterlibs.powermailJQueryFormValidationLanguage >
page.includeJSFooterlibs.powermailJQueryFormValidation >
```

in your setup TS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the browser-internal validation you can disable the php and js validation through "Constant Editor" --> "Powermail Additional" --> uncheck both checkbox. See attached screen.

[image]